# PHP exec response as string?

Tags: php, json, curl

I currently use the installed version of curl via exec() instead of using curl_exec() to query an API (linkedin). My call returns the good result but is weirdly encoded and I cannot transform it back to json.

Here is my code:

```
exec('curl "'.$url.'/v1/people/~?format=json" -H "Authorization: Bearer '.$token.'"', $data);
```

The response I get is (i replaced sensitive data with xxxx):

> array(7) { [0]=> string(1) "{" [1]=> string(22) " "firstName":
>   "xxxx"," [2]=> string(67) " "headline": "xxxx;"," [3]=> string(21) "
>   "id": "xxxx"," [4]=> string(24) " "lastName": "xxxx"," [5]=>
>   string(148) " "siteStandardProfileRequest": {"url":
>   "https://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=xxxx&authType=name&authToken=xxxx&trk=api*xxxx*xxxx*"}"
>   [6]=> string(1) "}" }

I've tried `json_encode(json_decode($data))` but it doesn't change anything... How can I transform this output into a JSON object?

Comment: have you heard of the `curl` extension for PHP? Way more elegant.

Comment: Yes I have but I find this way easier because I can actually run test calls directly in the prompt, calls that will be the exact same in PHP too...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do I find the answer once I post it lol. Anyway just in case someone faces the same issue, I solved it with:

```
$data = implode('', $data);
$data = json_decode($data);
```